# select options unable to show names - angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, html-select

I have this `select` which I'm populating through my `controller`. Or that was atleast was it was supposed to do.

I've been trying this

```
<select class="form-control selectWidth" 
    required 
    ng-model="template.type" 
    ng-init="template.type = template.type || types[0]"
    ng-options="type.name as type.name for type in types">

    <option style="display:none" value="" disabled>select a type</option>
</select>
```

the `$scope.types` from my controller

```
$scope.types = [
    { title:'cities', type:'city', templates: []},
    { title:'buildings', type:'building', templates: []}
];
```

the select adds the items, but the name won't show.

Comment: there is no name in the types list

Comment: try type.type and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change

```
type.name as type.name for type in type
```

with

```
type.title as type.title for type in type
```

or maybe

```
type.type as type.type for type in type
```

depending on what you are trying to display